# Choose Android wifi channel

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, android-ndk

I am trying to change the channel that the device is using to connect to wifi.
is it possible using WifiManager/any android api?
Should I use android NDK? if yes then can someone guide me through
the process of Get/Set channel of wifi in c?
Thanks

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to do? Do you only want it to connect to networks in a certain channel?

Comment: yes, I want to connect to wifi using channel number that I specify

Comment: Doesn't seem like you'll be able to do this without root or via the standard APIs AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

All the info from Wifi you can get with [ScanResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html) class. This class only describes information.

Wifi parameters are managed from router, no by the application, so you cannot change them with android.

Comment: I assume for instance, that the router chooses channel #4,
Is there a way to avoid the autoscan of the device for the needed channel (#4)? and choose it manually? the main goal is to avoid the full scan

Comment: Usually router choose a default channel. In some models(if not all), is possible to change it. This is used, in example, if 3 wifis are using same channel at same time, it will interface. If they are in different channels, the noise lesser.

Comment: Thanks @Piperoman, but I think you misunderstood my question. I was aiming to avoid the full scan of the application's wifi..the router always connects to channel #4..is there a way to manually connect my application to channel #4? without auto scan the channels?

Comment: AFAIK this it a S.O task, you try to use internet service, its scan channel and connect. I think that is not possible, I could be wrong.